# (Verification) $0^*$ is Identity Element for Summation of Real Numbers

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

**Definition of $\Bbb R$**

For two Cauchy sequences $\alpha,\beta : \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb Q$

Define $\alpha \sim \beta$ when $\forall e\;\;$ there  $\exists N$ s.t. $\forall i \ge N$, $\lvert \alpha(i)-\beta(i)\rvert \lt e$

Since $\sim$ is equivalence relation of the set $\Bbb F = \{\alpha: \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb Q$},

call the each element of quotient set, $\;\;F/\sim\;\;$, real number.

**Definition of  Summation among Real Numbers**

Define $[\alpha]+[\beta] = [\alpha+\beta]$ (*)

$\alpha + \beta$ is defined as $i \mapsto \alpha(i) + \beta(i)$

**Claim**

$0^*$ is identity element of operation (*)

$\forall r \in \Bbb Q\;$ define $r^*(i) = r, \;i\in\Bbb N$

**Proof**

$\forall \alpha:\Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$ we need to show

$[\alpha] + 0^* = [\alpha]$

$[\alpha] + 0^* = [\alpha + 0]$ by definition of (*) and $0^*$

Then $[\alpha + 0] = [\alpha]$ since $0 \in \Bbb Q$ is identity element of summation among rational numbers. Q.E.D.

Comment: I recall someone, whom I will assume to be you, posting a question with the same flaw in the definition of $\Bbb R$. I'll say it again, although for the problem at hand it is inconsequential: $\Bbb F$ must be the set of **CAUCHY** sequences $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$, not just the set of sequences. Otherwise that quotient will NOT be isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ and, truth to be told, it will not even be domain.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli that would be me again. Edited.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli have an additional question. any "one" word that denotes Cauchy-sequence of rational number?

Comment: The one given, for instance, by Wikipedia, or by any book: $\alpha:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N,\forall n,m\ge N,\ \lvert\alpha(n)-\alpha(m)\rvert<\varepsilon$$